# Parsing a single multi-line string of a specific format in C++

Tags: c++, string, date, parsing

```
"00:01:07,400-234-090\n
00:05:01,701-080-080\n
00:05:00,400-234-090"
```

I'm given a string in the format `hh-mm-ss,nnn-nnn-nnn` where `hh` is hours, `mm` is minutes and `ss` is seconds and `nnn-nnn-nnn` is a phone number. How can I parse this string one line at a time storing `hh`, `mm`, and `ss` into local variables and the phone number in an array?

Comment: where is your effort?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex expression for this. You could use regex like this -
`(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),([\d*-]*)` and get the hour, min, second and phone number from the substrings. Take a look at `libpcre` while you are at it.